# Jquery html() function to encode spaces in value parameter of option element

Tags: jquery, json

I am using JQuery's html() function to encode JSON values dynamically in a set of options drop downs. Most of my site works perfectly as expected:

```
$('#parameters').html('<option value={"name":"testsalary"}></option>');

<div id=​"parameters">​<option value=​"{"name":​"testsalary"}>​</option>​</div>​
```

however if the JSON object has a space it breaks by adding a double quote that was not originally there:

```
$('#parameters').html('<option value={"name":"test salary"}></option>');

<div id=​"parameters">​<option value=​"{"name":​"test" salary"}>​</option>​</div>​
```

Does anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add quote ' around your value

```
$('#parameters').html('<option value=\'{"name":"test salary"}\'></option>');
```

this will get you

```
<div id=​"parameters">​<option value=​'{"name":​"test salary"}'>​</option>​</div>​
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I decided to encode spaces as &nbsp and convert it on the backend when it is received.

So...

```
$('#parameters').html('<option value={"name":"test salary"}></option>');
```

becomes

```
$('#parameters').html('<option value={"name":"test&nbspsalary"}></option>');
```

Unfortunate that it does not encode the space in the value parameter.